# CRichEditCtrl LimitText

Tags: mfc

In MFC dialog based application I have CRichEditCtrl.

I want to limit the maximum number of text to be entered by the user is 1000 so I called CRichEditCtrl::LimitText(1000).

and then I called CRichEditCtrl::SetWindowText() with more than 1000 characters, now CRichEditCtrl dispays more than 1000 characters.

why SetWindowText is not considering LimitText value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/7xwdbt6b(v=vs.96)  Looks like you are setting this property more delayed in the form processing lifecycle. While debugging, does this line gets hit before the form is presented ?

Comment: At what point are you calling this? the app's `InitInstance()` (too early) or the dialog's `OnInitDialog()` (correct).

Comment: Sorry, limittext is working fine but If I call CRichEditCtrl::SetWindowText() with more than 1000 characters, now CRichEditCtrl dispays more than 1000 characters.SetWindowText() is not considering maximum limit value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `SetWindowText` is what interferes with it. It's intended behaviour.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/7xwdbt6b(v=vs.96)):

> Changing the text limit restricts only the text the user can enter. **It
>   has no effect on any text already in the edit control, nor does it
>   affect the length of the text copied to the edit control by the
>   SetWindowText member function in CWnd.** If an application uses the
>   SetWindowText function to place more text into an edit control than is
>   specified in the call to LimitText, the user can delete any of the
>   text within the edit control. However, the text limit will prevent the
>   user from replacing the existing text with new text, unless deleting
>   the current selection causes the text to fall below the text limit.